# Let $a,b,c$ are distinct integers. Then which among the following is the set of possible rank of $A$=

Tags: matrix-rank

Let $a,b,c$ are distinct integers. Then which among the following is the set of possible rank of
$$A = \begin{pmatrix}
a^2 & b^2 & c^2 \\
a^5 & b^5 & c^5 \\
a^{11} & b^{11} & c^{11}
\end{pmatrix}
$$

1. $\{0,1,2,3\}$
2. $\{1,2,3\}$
3. $\{2,3\}$
4. $\{3\}$

My Attempt:

$$A = \begin{pmatrix}
a^2 & b^2 & c^2 \\
a^5 & b^5 & c^5 \\
a^{11} & b^{11} & c^{11}
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Let $$det(A) = det\begin{pmatrix}
a^2 & b^2 & c^2 \\
a^5 & b^5 & c^5 \\
a^{11} & b^{11} & c^{11}
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Taking common $a^2,b^2,c^2$ from $C_1,C_2,C_3$ respectively, we get

$$det(A) = a^2b^2c^2. det\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 \\
a^3 & b^3 & c^3 \\
a^9 & b^9 & c^9
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Operating $C_1 \to C_1 - C_2$,$C_2 \to C_2 - C_3$, we get

$$det(A) = a^2b^2c^2. det\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1 \\
a^3-b^3 & b^3-c^3 & c^3 \\
a^9-b^9 & b^9-c^9 & c^9
\end{pmatrix}
$$
$$det(A) = a^2b^2c^2. det\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1 \\
a^3-b^3 & b^3-c^3 & c^3 \\
(a^3-b^3)(a^6+b^6+a^3b^3) &(b^3-c^3)(b^6+c^6+b^3c^3) & c^3
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Taking $(a^3-b^3),(b^3-c^3)$ common from $C_1,C_2$ respectively, we get

$$det(A) = a^2b^2c^2(a^3-b^3)(b^3-c^3).
 det\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & c^3 \\
(a^6+b^6+a^3b^3) &(b^6+c^6+b^3c^3) & c^3
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Expanding by $R_1$, we get
$det(A) = a^2b^2c^2(a^3-b^3)(b^3-c^3)[-(a^6+b^6+a^3b^3)+(b^6+c^6+b^3c^3)] =  a^2b^2c^2(a^3-b^3)(b^3-c^3)[(c^6-a^6)+b^3(c^3-a^3)] = a^2b^2c^2(a^3-b^3)(b^3-c^3)[((c^3)^2-(a^3)^2)+b^3(c^3-a^3)] = a^2b^2c^2(a^3-b^3)(b^3-c^3)[(c^3-a^3)(c^3+a^3)+b^3(c^3-a^3)] = a^2b^2c^2(a^3-b^3)(b^3-c^3)(c^3-a^3)(a^3+b^3+c^3)$

If $a \neq b \neq c$ then Rank of $A$ may be $3$. I could not determine other possibility of ranks. Please help me.

Comment: If $a = 0$ isn't the rank automatically at most $2$ ?

Comment: Oh ok good work, it seems you showed the rank is $3$ whenever none of those factors is $0$ which seems to always hold if $a^3+b^3+c^3 \neq  0$ and all variables are distinct and non-zero.

Comment: No, take $0,1,2$ or $1,0,2$ or $1,2,0$. In all cases, $a^3+b^3+c^3 \neq 0$ but $det(A) = 0$

Comment: yeah but you're taking one of them to be $0$ :p

Comment: I edited question. Please review it again. I replaced "real numbers" by "integers"

Comment: Have you tried reading my answer ?

Comment: Yes, but I could not understand "The rank cannot be $1$ either, wlog $a,b\neq 0$, it follows that the second column must be a scalar multiple of the first, it follows $a^2/b^2 = a^5/b^5$ and so $(a/b)^3 = 1 \implies a/b = 1$."

Comment: I added a bit more explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you noted there are examples where the rank is $3$, for an example where the rank is $2$ take $a=0,b=1,c=-1$ or whatever.

The rank cannot be $0$ clearly.

The rank cannot be $1$ either, assume the rank is $1$. Without loss of generality both $a$ and $b$ are different to $0$, it follows that if the rank is $1$ then the second column must be a scalar multiple of the first,let $\lambda$ be the scalar, then  $\lambda = a^2/b^2$ and $\lambda = a^5/b^5$ and so $(a/b)^3 = 1 \implies a/b = 1$, contradicting $a\neq b$.

Comment: Very Nice explanation. Thank you very much.